# How does the review work?

Tags: rules, cricket

I've seen both the teams reviewing on a Test/ODI match. So there could be two scenarios such as:

```
1) When the batsman is given out, and the batsman reviews against
it.

2) When the batsman is not given out, the bowling team could review
it.
```

So for example, it's an `LBW` given for a batsman, and it's the umpire's call. The batsman tries to review it. When the third umpire sees the seam position, whether it has pitched in line and whether it's knocking the stumps. So if the batsman reviews this, what could be the reasons for the umpire to turn down this decision? ie: If it misses the stumps or pitching outside the line?

And I would like to know the vice versa when, umpire gives it not out when the bowling team appeals and they take the review. What could be the scenarios if it should be given out?

All in all, does the standing umpire's call matter when a review is made? Can a dismissal be turned down due the on field umpire's call?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the rules for the system? It's far easier to clarify something you've already read or watched, than to teach you everything you could discover in your own.

Comment: Could I know the reason for the downvote? So that I can improve my question ?
@Nij I've not gone through the official rules as such, just following the rules from the match. So I din have the exact idea about giving a dismissal after reviewing it.

Comment: see the above. A lot of your questions are trivially answered by simply reading the regulations. There are some aspects which aren't well-explained, but to go through all of those *ab initio*, or without knowing the "easy bits" first, would be a huge time sink. Read the official sources - they're easily found - and then ask about specific things that still trouble you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without going into the specifics of each type of dismissal, the general principle is if there is doubt, the on field Umpire's call stands. The review has to be able to conclusively demonstrate that the Umpire was wrong in order to over-turn the decision. This is a different statement than the review simply makes the most likely decision, given the evidence.